# Python: count frequency of words from a column and store the results into another column on my data frame

Tags: python, pandas, count, counter, frame

I want to count the number of each word that appears in each row of one column ('Comment') and store in a new column ('word') on my data frame called headlamp.
I'm trying with the following down code, however, I get and error.

```
for i in range(0,len(headlamp)):
    headlamp['word'].apply(lambda text: Counter(" ".join(headlamp['Comment'][i].astype(str)).split(" ")).items())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a0c20291b4f5> in <module>()
  1 for i in range(0,len(headlamp)):
  ----> 2     headlamp['word'].apply(lambda text: Counter("".join(headlamp['Comment'][i].astype(str)).split(" ")).items())

  C:\Users\Rafael\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
  1995             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
  1996         else:
  -> 1997             return self._getitem_column(key)
  1998 
  1999     def _getitem_column(self, key):

  C:\Users\Rafael\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _getitem_column(self, key)
  2002         # get column
  2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
  -> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)
  2005 
  2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

  C:\Users\Rafael\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in _get_item_cache(self, item)
  1348         res = cache.get(item)
  1349         if res is None:
  -> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)
   1351             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1352             cache[item] = res

   C:\Users\Rafael\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3288 
   3289             if not isnull(item):
   -> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3291             else:
   3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

   C:\Users\Rafael\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:
   -> 1947                 returnself._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   1948 
   1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

   pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)()

   pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)()

   pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()

   pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()

   KeyError: 'word'
```

Any help will be highly appreciate

Comment: Hello, what is the expected format of the column storing each word frequency ? A `dict`, a column by word ?

Comment: Can you post your dataframe head? You're getting a `KeyError: 'word'` when trying to find the column `headlamp['word']`

Comment: Thank for your reply @rfw,
I want to put all the count for each word on the column 'comment' on the new column 'word'
Therefore, this new column 'word' will be created.
The reason for that, is because i want to know how many times a particular word had appear on each comment to find out the problem related to the headlamp (automotive part)
Please tell if you still want to post here the dataframe

Comment: Let me see if i got it: you have a "comment" column with a string like this "this is a simple comment". Then you want to run, in each row, a function that counts the number of occurrences of each word, and write this new "dict" into a new column called "words". Correct?

Comment: you complety got it @rfw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
headlamp['word'] = headlamp['Comment'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
```

**Example:**

```
headlamp = pd.DataFrame({'Comment': ['hello world','world','foo','foo and bar']})
print(headlamp)
       Comment
0  hello world
1        world
2          foo
3  foo and bar

headlamp['word'] = headlamp['Comment'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
print(headlamp)
       Comment  word
0  hello world     2
1        world     1
2          foo     1
3  foo and bar     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [most_common()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method you can achieve what you want.

Feel free to use this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'Comment': ['This has has words words words that are written twice twice', 'This is a comment without repetitions', 'This comment, has ponctuations!']}, index = [0, 1, 2])

#you must create the new column before trying to assing any value
df['Words'] = ""

#counting frequencies
i = 0
for row in df['Comment']:
    df['Words'][i] = str(Counter(row.split()).most_common())
    i+=1

print df
```

Output:

```
                                             Comment  \
0  This has has words words words that are writte...   
1              This is a comment without repetitions   
2                    This comment, has ponctuations!   

                                               Words  
0  [('words', 3), ('twice', 2), ('has', 2), ('tha...  
1  [('a', 1), ('comment', 1), ('This', 1), ('is',...  
2  [('This', 1), ('comment,', 1), ('has', 1), ('p...
```

Comment: Thank your help you @rfw

Comment: Hoewver, I couldn't reach the results
I have also imported the counter

Comment: However, when i created the new column I got a warning:

   C:\Users\Rafael\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-      packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

   See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
    if __name__ == '__main__':

Comment: And then after I ran the code you wrote, I got an error for my framedata
      1 i = 0
      2 for row in headlamp['Comment']:
----> 3     headlamp['word'][i] = str(Counter(row.astype(str).split()).most_common())
      4     i+=1
      5 print headlamp['word']

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'

I used the code:

Comment: i = 0
for row in headlamp['Comment']:
    headlamp['word'][i] = str(Counter(row.split()).most_common())
    i+=1
print headlamp['word']

Do you have any idea what went wrong

Comment: As your error message says: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.`. So, is `headlamp` a slice of another dataframe? If so, instead of creating a slice, assign it to a new dataframe...

Comment: I believe we are getting there, headlamp is a dataframe, I has used `type(headlamp)` to confirm it, and the results was `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` however, I assured that by using `headlamp = pd.DataFrame(headlamp)`, I could create the `headlamp['word'] = ""`, but the problem happened again on next part of script `i = 0
for row in headlamp['Comment']:
    headlamp['word'][i] = str(Counter(row.split()).most_common())
    i+=1
print headlamp['word']`,

Comment: ithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`. The headlamp was created by the this code: `headlamp = ro[ro['PN 3D']=="921"]`, `ro` is the original dataframe. So, what went wrong on mine script, thank you in advance @rfw

Comment: and then finally the warning, the error appeared: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-8427f49dc953> in <module>()
      1 i = 0
      2 for row in headlamp['Comment']:
----> 3     headlamp['word'][i] = str(Counter(row.split()).most_common())
      4     i+=1
      5 print headlamp['word']
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: how can i get only values from results? (words,twices,...)